# Searching the objectDTO from ArrayList<objectDTO> based on the attribute value inside subDTO

Tags: java

Whats the best way to search element from the arraylist based on the attribute value of another subDTO .

> *Scenario*: I have Employee Object, it has another ContactDetails Object. 
>   I need to find  Employee from list of Employees whose ext extNumber is 1234 (extNumber is attribute inside ContactDetails.  I need to check if the ext is available while creating the new employee and allocating the new ext.
>
> > can't use the JDBC query directly as I am consuming corba api. Don't have any corba api that provides such search.

The DTO has another subDto.

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private ContactDetails contact;
}

public class ContactDetails {
  private String number;
}
```

> *How I am doing it currently*:   I am looping over the list and check the extNumber like below

```
public boolean isTelephoneExtAvailable(String telephoneExt, List<Employee> employeeList) {
        boolean isAvailable = true;
        if(null != employeeList) {
        Iterator<Employee> itr = employeeList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            employeeList emp = itr.next();
            ContactDetails  contact = emp .getContactDetails();
            if(null != contact && null != contact.getNumber()){
                if(contact.getNumber().equals(telephoneExt)){
                    isAvailable = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

Is there any better optimized way to achieve this?

Comment: Override collection contains method to compare the sub object

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Java 8 than I would do it for example like this (StringUtils from apache commons):

```
return !employeeList.stream().anyMatch(employee -> 
              employee.getContactDetails()!=null && 
              StringUtils.equals(telephoneExt, employee.getContactDetails().getNumber()))
```